# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 results in kernel panic

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, updates

I've been upgrading my ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 through [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts) guide.

This is what i did,

First,
I did `sudo apt-get update` and it updated successfully.

Then,
I did `sudo apt-get upgrade` and it downloaded packages around 300MB or something.

After than,
I did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` which downloaded about 800MB of data.

Then the system restarted. Now it's not booting up. 
As of now, It just shows a blank screen and my `CAPS-LOCK INDICATOR` is blinking infinitely.

How can i solve this problem ? Please help. If you need more clarification, ask me in the comments.

Edit:

Now I've ENABLED Secure Boot from BIOS, and now am getting some errors on the screen.

[image: BootScreen]

Comment: Try to boot on old kernel. Hold Shift down when starting up, to enter Grub menu, and choose kernel to boot on.

Comment: I've selected 3.19.0-74-generic.. it's just a terminal. How can i get back into the GUI ?